# No se pudo crear una instancia de las siguientes clases

Tags: kotlin

buenas noches alguien me podría ayudar con esto .No se pudo crear una instancia de las siguientes clases:
androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView es un error que me aparece en el xml. es un proyecto nuevo
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLXYb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWrJK.png)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.